# How do I tell a Javascript method to wait until after binding values to execute in DotVVM?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dotvvm

I use a value binding (`<dot:HtmlLiteral Html="{value: BannerHTML}" class="mainBanner"/>`) to generate some of my page content based on a number of variables.

I also need to run some javascript on the generated HTML to fix a few minor niggles, like matching font size for unusual scaling scenarios and the like. As standard, I place executable javascript at the *end* of an HTML document.

Generated HTML in one of these scenarios:

```
<div class="mainBanner" data-bind="html: BannerHTML">
    <div class="mainBanner-upper">some text</div>
    <div class="mainBanner-face" id="mainTitle">some other text</div>
    <div class="mainBanner-lower">some more text</div>
</div>
```

JS to operate on that HTML:
(requires https://github.com/adactio/FitText.js)

```
window.fitText(document.getElementById("mainTitle"));
```

As far as I can see, the javascript executes before the HTML is generated, and javascript that is executed on the element returns `Cannot read property 'xyz' of null`. How do I tell it to wait? I tried both binding the javascript file to a resource, and simply writing it in with `<script>` tags at the end of the body element without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your problem seems to be DOM related, I can propose you two approches.

1. Your javascript must check and wait for DOM. On which I strongly suggest you to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/3708721) to [...how to call a function when the page/DOM is ready...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)
2. Add your script dynamically after your data is binded (I'm not really sure about this)

Good luck.

### EDIT

So I went and took a look to the dotvvm documentation to look for events calls and noticed something interesting :

*Every DotVVM page includes Dotvvm.js which defines dotvvm in the global scope. This object can be used to access viewmodel and react to various page events.*

This allows you to access specifics events fired by DOTVVM, you only have to find the one you need in your case. I provided you with an example below.

You could try something like this (the event may no be the one you need) :

```
<script>
    //By subscribing to the event, your code will only be executed 
    // if "init" event is fired by dotvvvm
    dotvvm.events.init.subscribe(()=>{ 
        window.fitText(document.getElementById("mainTitle"));  
        //basically enclose the content of your script tag with this.
    });
</script>
```

Please do read the documentation as I may have omitted something ? [DOTVVM Javascript Events](https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/tutorials/advanced-javascript-events-and-client-side-viewmodel/2.0)

Comment: The first example in that answer demonstrates placing executable JS in the page *after* any HTML. That's my standard approach - which indicates to me that DotVVM is doing something *after* the DOM is loaded using KnockoutJS. 

I think what I need to do is listen for a certain call to be made, then execute my JS afterwards. My problem now is that I don't quite know how to find calls in the first place... I'm not that familiar with JS.

Comment: Okay, so on my end, I'm not familiar with DotVVM or even the interpolation of JS with asp.net. I looked a bit on the DotVVM documentation and found this page : https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/tutorials/advanced-javascript-events-and-client-side-viewmodel/2.0

Comment: I updated my answer to try and provide you with an example using DOTVVM javascript events.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! I'm making a slight edit as the actual syntax is a little different, but your premise is exactly what I was looking for. Just took a while to see it.

Comment: Happy to read it, If you have a question don't hesitate. Happy coding :)

Comment: Actually I can't seem to edit, so here's the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fyt48vp6/

Comment: To make sure the <script> is executed after DotVVM is loaded, I recommend doing this:

1. For inline scripts, use `<dot:InlineScript Dependencies="dotvvm">...</dot:InlineScript>`. You can use the control anywhere, DotVVM will make sure it will run after the framework itself is loaded.

2. If the script is longer, I recommend to put it in a separate file, and register it as a resource (again with dependency on `dotvvm` so the correct order is maintained). https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/tutorials/basics-javascript-and-css/2.0